# Change type of map

Tags: r

I have code to show points on the map as below:

```
m <- leaflet(mdt) %>% 
    addTiles('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', attribution='Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>') m %>% 
    addCircles(~mdt$Pickup_longitude, ~mdt$Pickup_latitude, popup=mdt$Trip_type, weight = 3, radius=40,                   color="#ffa500", stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.8) %>% 
    addCircles(~mdt$Dropoff_longitude, ~mdt$Dropoff_latitude, popup=mdt$Trip_type, weight = 3, radius=40,                    color="#9dea3f", stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.8  ) %>% 
    addLegend("bottomright", colors= "#ffa500", labels="NYC'", title="Pickup & Drop off Locations")
```

My Map look is like this:

[image]

How can I change the type of map, I would like to use open street maps with clear color like this:

[image]

I want to change only type of map. what is the easiest way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is answer for those who may occur with same issue.

```
m <- leaflet(mdt) %>% addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(opacity = .5)) m %>% addCircles(~mdt$Pickup_longitude, ~mdt$Pickup_latitude, popup=mdt$Trip_type, weight = 3, radius=40, color="#8B008B", stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.8) %>% addCircles(~mdt$Dropoff_longitude, ~mdt$Dropoff_latitude, popup=mdt$Trip_type, weight = 3, radius=40, 
               color="#00FF00", stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.8  )
```